# What is the better method to implement drawing in my application by 3rd party plugins?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, c++builder

i created the app and all the plugins written for it should draw on special place on my form that will be random or specially selected for plugin, so everytime the coordinates is random. Also they should use standard windows GDI functions like Rectangle(), FillRect(), TextOutA() and other.
What is the better method to accomplish this? I know i should make drawing engine inside my program, i have 2 choices: to use named pipes or to use windows messages. Maybe someone have another methods implemented and tested?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use GDI functions, they need access to an `HDC` handle.  If your app sets aside a `TPanel` or other suitable windowed container for drawing, then it can pass the container's `HWND` handle to the plugin and then the plugin can obtain the `HDC` manually via `GetDC()` or `GetWindowDC()` when needed.  If you chose to pass the actual `HDC` to the plugin instead, then you can set aside a `TPaintBox` or other suitable non-windowed container instead, which does not require a dedicated `HWND` and associated resources.

Comment: thanks, i prefer to do GetDCEx() extracting a clipped region from form HDC to plugins HDC, but will this handle be valid for another process?

Comment: @Sergey: No it will not, but if your plugins are DLLs then they will run in the address space of your main exe process, and so it is safe to pass handles across the DLL boundary.